# LabVIEW: How to pass a value from callback vi to main vi

Tags: callback, labview

I have the .NET library which communicates with our camera and I am writing a LabVIEW VI to control our camera through the .NET library. From time to time the camera's state in the library is updated depending on how the camera is used (idle, live, none, and etc) and I want LabVIEW to pick up the change.

Looking at the following example, using a callback seems the right way to do, but I am not sure:

- how to pass the updated value from the callback vi to the main vi
- how to inform main.vi that callback was invoked by the .NET library

As an example I want to pass an integer value from the callback to main vi but I can't figure it out.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks!

[image: main.vi front panel]
[image: main.vi control panel]
[image: callback.vi control panel]
Note that I manually update xValue from the main.vi to trigger a callback. What I want to do is that once the callback is called by .NET I want to print the updated xValue from the callback to the indicator shown in main.vi

I applied Yair's suggestion but when I'm dequeueing I am not getting "invoked" state even though callback is called.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Drop the register callback node.
2. Create a user event in the main VI. Make the data (the xValue integer, in your case) a typedef if there is any chance at all you will modify it. Register for the user event in the main VI using a Register for Events node and handle it using an event structure.
3. Wire the user event into the **User Parameter** input of the register node.
4. If you now create the callback VI, you will have the event reference as the user parameter and you can generate the user event inside the callback VI using the **Generate User Event** primitive.

Now, each time the callback VI runs, it will generate the event and the main VI will have it in its event queue.

Comment: could you take a look at the uploaded photo ? I am not getting the "invoked" state when I'm dequeuing.

Comment: You're not actually doing what I said. For one thing, you're using queues and not events, but that's OK, because it's also a valid way to pass the data.  
  
The real thing you're not doing is parts 3 and 4 of my suggestion, so you actually have different queues (one in the main VI and one for each call of the callback VI), which is why you're not getting anything in the main VI. You need to pass the queue reference you created in the main VI to the callback VI and use that to enqueue the data.    
  
There are also example online and in the example finder of how to work with callbacks.